# UINavigationController popToViewController appears triggered twice

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Can anyone explain what would cause a call to:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:self animated:YES]
```

To start, get half-way, then appear to restart, where the popping `UIViewController` jumps all the way back to the left edge, the animation begins again, and then completes?

It is as if it has been called twice, but to debug I subclassed `UINavigationController` and placed breakpoints in both `popToViewController` and `popViewControllerAnimated`, and only popToViewController is called once.

When I call

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:self animated:NO];
```

It behaves exactly as expected, but obviously without the animation, which I would like to see.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this on questions before where people added multiple actions for something like "TouchUpInside" and "TouchDownInside".

If you're using storyboards you may want to look at what actions are connected to your buttons.

Or another possibility is doing it through storyboards and code.

Answer (score 0):

I have uncovered the cause - I had an iOS [toast UI library](https://github.com/cruffenach/CRToast/) that was triggering in the middle of a navigation event that was disruption the transition.